# Have two identical html tags, only want text from second tag

Tags: python, html

I have an HTML file with 2 tags with the same tag "textarea", I only want the text from the second of those tags. How would I do that?

I already have code in place to find text from the "textarea" tag:

```
for dk_desc in soup.find_all(re.compile("textarea")):
        final3 = dk_desc.text
```

but this provides me with text from both tags.

The HTML code (only partial sample provided due to size):

```html
<li class="property_value">
  <textarea cols="40" id="id_1290-snippet" name="1290-snippet" rows="10" style="width:100%">&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;It has been detected, that the installed version of Oracle Application Server is&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;XXXX.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;This version is known to be vulnerable to a number of unspecified vulnerabilities, categorized as 'urgent'.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;As this version is no longer supported for this platform, updates or patches may no longer be released, which have the consequence that vulnerabilities can not be patched, leaving the system vulnerable.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;In version 10.1.2.0.2 there are, according to http://www.cvedetails.com more than 54 vulnerabilities which affects the installed version.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: center; line-height: normal;" align="center"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 8pt;"&gt;Figure 1: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 8pt;"&gt;Oracle Application Server version.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;More information on these vulnerabilities can be found at:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="color: blue; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;"&gt;http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="color: blue; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;It is recommended that the installed version is updated as soon as possible to the latest version.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
</li>
<li class="property_value">
  <textarea cols="40" id="id_172-snippet" name="172-snippet" rows="10" style="width:100%">&lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;Det konstateret, at den installerede version af Oracle Application Server er&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;XXXX.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;Denne version indeholder flere kendte samt uspecificeret s&amp;aring;rbarheder, der kategoriseres som v&amp;aelig;rende 'yderst kritiske' og 'kritiske'.&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;Da der ikke l&amp;aelig;ngere komme opdateringer til denne platform, vil disse s&amp;aring;rbarheder ikke blive udbedret, hvorfor systemet er meget udsat.&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;I version 10.1.2.0.2 findes der if&amp;oslash;lge http://www.cvedetails.com ikke mindre end 54 s&amp;aring;rbarheder, der ber&amp;oslash;rer denne version. Mere information om disse findes p&amp;aring; adressen&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;Det anbefales leverand&amp;oslash;ren af software l&amp;oslash;sningen kontakts, s&amp;aring; der hurtigst muligt kan opgraderes til en nyere, supporteret version.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
</li>
<li class="property_name">
  Scan type
</li>
<li class="property_value">
  <select multiple="multiple" name="scan_type" size="6" style="width:100%">
    <option selected="selected" value="5">
      COMPANY PCI
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7">
      Other
    </option>
    <option value="8">
      Firewall Audit
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="6">
      Penetration Test
    </option>
    <option value="9">
      WIFI Test
    </option>
    <option value="10">
      APP Test
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">
      External Security Analysis
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">
      Internal Security Analysis
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">
      Web Application Test
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">
      Host Discovery Analysis
    </option>
  </select>
  -- Use ctrl to mark multiple types
</li>
<li class="property_name">
  Update
</li>
<li class="property_value">
  <input type="submit" value="Update snippet"/>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
<br style="clear:both;"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="/media/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/media/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/media/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/js/editor.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this simple?

```
all_the_textareas = soup.find_all(re.compile("textarea"))
text_from_second_area = all_the_textareas[1].text
```

Comment: Well not quite.. It seems the text is more fragmented, but [6] gave me the text i needed, so I guess it works :) Ty very much